# how to get Google groups contents by using directory API or Cloud Identity API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, issue-tracking, google-directory-api, google-groups-api, google-cloud-identity

Can anyone please suggest to me how to get the content of google groups by using 2 different API

1. Cloud identity API
2. google directory API

We need to get the google group content.

Answer (score 1):

Well, both APIs can interact with Google groups, however, there are subtle differences between them than you can check [here](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F10427204%3Fhl%3Den&product_context=10427204&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a).

I would strongly recommend using the **Directory API** as it has better documentation and as the **Cloud Identity API** requires either a **Cloud Identity Free** or a **Cloud Identity Premium** account. But of course, either of them can be used.

---

### Directory API

For **Directory API** I would recommend taking a look at the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/quickstarts-overview), as everything regarding the API's setup in your favorite programming language is explained there.

The documentation on how to deal with groups is [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups).

Of course, **Apps Script** is the most straightforward tool to fetch that information, as it can be achieved in a few lines (and adding the **AdminDirectory** service):

```js
function myFunction() {

  var groupList = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({customer:"my_customer"})["groups"];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < groupList.length; i++){ 
    console.log(groupList[i].name+": " + groupList[i].description);
  }
}
```

---

### Cloud Identity API

Regarding **Cloud Identity API**, you will need to follow this [setup](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/setup).

Then, the documentation regarding groups can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/create-google-groups).

As an example, here is how it could be done in **Apps Script**:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var customerId = AdminDirectory.Users.get(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()).customerId;

  var url = "https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1beta1/groups?parent=customers/"+customerId;
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  };
  
    var groups = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params).getContentText()).groups;
    
    for(var i = 0; i< groups.length;i++){
      console.log(groups[i].displayName); 
    }
}
```

For that you would also need to append the following line in the  **appscript.json** manifest file. You can open it by going to **Project Settings** -> **Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor**:

```js
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups"]
```